# Getting just the filename from HTTP post

Tags: ruby

I have a string which is this: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/test.jpg". This is a location and I am trying to only get the file's name as a string.

Is there a way to just extract the file's name (test.jpg) from that string with ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below :-

```
string = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/test.jpg"
File.basename(string) # => "test.jpg"
```

Checkout the doco of [`::basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-basename).

Comment: thanks. it extacts the file's name (excluding the type, i.e. jpg). I only get the string "test"

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the optimal way but you can just split by / and save the last value

```
string = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/test.jpg".split('/')
string = string[string.length-1] # => "test.jpg"
```